Using Kalman Filter to Estimate Scale Changes in Real-Time Camera Preview
I'm currently working on a real-time image processing application where I need to dynamically adjust the scale of objects in a live camera feed. The goal is to maintain consistent object sizing in the display as the camera or objects move closer or farther from the lens. I am considering using a Kalman filter for this task and would appreciate advice or validation on this approach.
Any advice and code snippets will help
Thanks
well my goal is to calculate the area of the garden i want to do it for android  How can i do this i was thinking to solve this problem using the kalman filter

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Well this is what  i'm thinking right now if it is possible to do so can Kalman filter and help me or not  I might be wrong for this one  but this is my assumption  i want anyone if know its possible can help me in frame the soultion so i can start to code.
